# How to perform unit test of a controller which is not having model folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I have a MVC project created which is not having model created, and below is my controller code which requires unit test created. I have checked multiple documents which tells you to use model class during unit test, however as I mentioned I donot have a model class. Is there a way to test this api in asp.net?

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult NetWorth(decimal chequing, decimal savTax, decimal raiDayFund, decimal savFun, decimal savTravel, decimal saveDevel)
{
    decimal totalAssets = chequing + savTax + raiDayFund + savFun + savTravel + saveDevel;
    return Json(totalAssets);
    // return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's generaly a bad practice to put logic inside controller layer. You'll prefer having a logic layer that do the calculation (chequing + savTax + raiDayFund + savFun + savTravel + saveDevel). This layer can be easily unit tested.

```
public class CalculationService
{
    public decimal CalculateTotalAssets(decimal chequing, decimal savTax, decimal raiDayFund, decimal savFun, decimal savTravel, decimal saveDevel)
    {
        return chequing + savTax + raiDayFund + savFun + savTravel + saveDevel;
    }
}
```

I Hope this help you to design your application.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a model to create a test.

```
[TestMethod]
      public void Net_Worth_Test(){
         // Arrange: define your controller here
         HomeController controller = new HomeController();

         // Act: Pass your parameters to the method and get the result
         JsonResult result = controller.NetWorth(10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 20) as JsonResult;

         // Assert: Check the result with your expected answer.
         Assert.IsNotNull(result);
         Assert.IsEqual(150, result.Value);


      }
```